# Set defaults from JSON schema during validation

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I try to make a validator that would set defaults from a JSON schema during validation.

I found this question: [Trying to make JSON Schema validator in Python to set default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290777/trying-to-make-json-schema-validator-in-python-to-set-default-values) and adjusted it a bit.
Since I use "jsonschema==3.2.0", I came up with such a code:

```py
def _with_default_setter_extension(validator_class):
    """Extend validator class with defaults setter.

    With this extension, the validator class will set all defaults from a
    schema being validated to a validated instance.
    """

    def _set_defaults(validator, properties, instance, schema):
        if not validator.is_type(instance, "object"):
            return

        valid = True
        for prop, subschema in properties.items():
            if prop in instance:
                for error in validator.descend(
                    instance[prop],
                    subschema,
                    path=prop,
                    schema_path=prop,
                ):
                    valid = False
                    yield error

        # set defaults only when validation is successful
        if valid:
            # set root default when instance is empty
            if not instance and "default" in schema:
                instance.update(schema["default"])
                return

            for prop, subschema in properties.items():
                if "default" in subschema and not isinstance(instance, list):
                    instance.setdefault(prop, subschema["default"])

    return jsonschema.validators.extend(
        validator_class, {"properties": _set_defaults}
    )
```

It works good except one case which is important for me. I wrote such a test to prove it does not work for my case:

```py
def test_defaults_from_oneOf_only_defaults_from_valid_schema_are_set():
    """When oneOf is used, I expect only defaults from the valid subschema to be set."""
    schema = {
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "properties": {
                    "p": {"enum": ["one"]},
                    "params": {"properties": {"q": {"default": 1}}},
                }
            },
            {
                "properties": {
                    "p": {"enum": ["two"]},
                    "params": {"properties": {"w": {"default": 2}}},
                }
            },
        ],
    }
    assert _VALIDATOR.validate({"p": "two", "params": {}}, schema) == {
        "p": "two",
        "params": {"w": 2},
    }
```

The test fails with this assertion error:

```
AssertionError: assert {'p': 'two', 'params': {'q': 1, 'w': 2}} == {'p': 'two', 'params': {'w': 2}}
  +{'p': 'two', 'params': {'q': 1, 'w': 2}}
  -{'p': 'two', 'params': {'w': 2}}
  Full diff:
  - {'p': 'two', 'params': {'w': 2}}
  + {'p': 'two', 'params': {'q': 1, 'w': 2}}
  ?
```

So we can see, that despite the first subschema is invalid, the default value ("q") from its "params" is set.
With some debugging, I discovered that when you override only the "properties" validator, it lacks context. So when the first subschema "params" gets validated, I have no context telling me that "p" param validation failed and we are still in the same subschema.

Please, give me any insight into what I could try.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the words in the original jsonschema [Q&A doc](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#why-doesn-t-my-schema-s-default-property-set-the-default-on-my-instance):

> In this code, we add the default properties to each object before the
> properties are validated, so the default values themselves will need
> to be valid under the schema.

And you are running the validation and set_default with the extended validator. That is why the dict is updated still. You might want to run them with a separated validator for validation only first.